# Detect if printer support duplex programmatically using obj-c

Tags: objective-c, printing, duplex

I have been stumped by this for the last few days. I need to detect if a printer support duplex printing.

I have had partial success using code like:

```
NSPrinter * printer = [NSPrinter printerWithName:pname];

[printInfo setPrinter:printer];

PMPrintSettings settings = printInfo.PMPrintSettings;
PMDuplexMode pmDuplexMode = 0;
OSStatus status = PMGetDuplex(settings, &pmDuplexMode);
supportsDuplex = (status >= 0);
```

But this only work if I captured a full printerConfig through an NSPrintPanel. What I need is a way to detect if a printer with a specific name support duplex without requiring the user to 1st open a panel. I would like to do if for any printer defined on the local Mac. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, I doubt that it's correct to interpret positive `status` as indicating support. In general, any value other than zero (`noErr`) is a failure of some sort.

If you're confident that `PMGetDuplex()` returns an error for a print settings object when the printer doesn't support duplex, you can try this approach: create a session with `PMCreateSession()`, obtain a `PMPrinter` using `PMPrinterCreateFromPrinterID()` or by searching the array returned from `PMSessionCreatePrinterList()` for on which matches whatever criteria you want, set the session to use that printer using `PMSessionSetCurrentPMPrinter()`, create a print settings object with `PMCreatePrintSettings()`, call `PMSessionDefaultPrintSettings()` to initialize the print settings from the session, call `PMSessionValidatePrintSettings()` just for good measure, then call `PMGetDuplex()` and check the return value.

It might also be worth trying to set a duplex mode with `PMSetDuplex()` and check the return code and, possibly, calling `PMSessionValidatePrintSettings()` and checking if it changed that setting.